# Renumbering Identical Field Values

Tags: sql, ms-access

I have a table with field values that are identical (0). I want to renumber them sequentially backwards starting with -1. There are about 1800 rows with this field value. Is there a way to do this with a query? I'd rather not use VBA for this task if I don't have to.

Comment: is this renumbering a one-time task, or will the data be updating and thus requiring numbering of new rows?

Comment: also, what columns does your table have other than the field with the zeroes?  If there's a primary key or other unique ID field it might be possible.

Comment: @Rominus Yes this is a one-time task. There is an autonumber column. There are 15 columns total, most with unique data, but I am only interested in renumbering those 0's.

Comment: Ok.  Honestly, the easiest way to do it once is to export to Excel, number there, and reimport. But I think I can come up with a SQL query for it too.

Comment: Does the table include rows with values other than 0 in the field you're talking about?

Comment: For some context, there are about 46000 total rows. There are many duplicates in this specific field but as I said, I'm only needing to eliminate the 0's from that column. I want to use negative numbers so they are easily distinguishable elsewhere in the database where queries are based on that field. I'd love to be able to stay in Access for this. Excel and I are not friends on this work PC.

Comment: This is easy and straightforward with a recordset loop in VBA. Why don't you want to use that?

Answer (score 0):

You can use an autonumber field to generate your numbers.

Since you have rows with different values than 0 in the field you need to number, it gets sloppy.  You would extract the '0' rows, place them an interim table with its own autonumber field (start value 1, increment by +1), run this query (for this example it would be called newnum_qry).

```
SELECT autonumber, autonumber-(autonumber*2) as newnumber , [your other columns]
FROM int_tbl
```

and then return the rows to the original table, leaving the autonumber from the interim table behind.  Query to remerge:

```
SELECT source_of_zeroes, null as newnumber, [your other columns]
    FROM orig_tbl
    WHERE source_of_zeroes != 0
UNION
    SELECT source_of_zeroes, newnumber, [your other columns]
    FROM newnum_qry
```

This is solution is, IMO, really junky.  There's should be a better way, but as is often the case in Access, junk may be the best you can do.

Comment: Thank you. I'll try this tomorrow and let you know how it works out.